# Какие файлы обязательно скрыть с помощью htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

При создании нового сайта есть файлы видные пользователям (к примеру страница регистрации, страница добавлении новостей), есть файлы обработчики (например: нажал на отправить новость и он через обработчик перенаправляется, указывая успешно опубликован новость или ошибка).
Какие файлы скрыть с помощью htaccess без вреда функционалам сайта?

Comment: Те, скрытие которых, не нанесет вред функционалам сайта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В современном приложении единственный РНР файл, лежащий в корне сайта - это index.php. Остальные программные файлы лежат выше корня сайта и недоступны для прямого запроса к веб-серверу.

Если же говорить о приложении старого образца, состоящего из отдельных файлов, то никакие закрывать не надо. Все равно они никому даром не нужны.

Comment: Поддерживаю. Только еще не забыть оставить открытыми стили, скрипты и картинки